# How can I take advantage of a change in recursion?

Tags: c#

I have one problem with recursive function. The function does what is required of it.

```
public static int ControlNumber(int Q)
        {

            if (//some condition)
            {

              return some digit;

            }
            else
            {
                return ControlNumber(Q+1);
            }


        }
```

The problem occurs when else is completed. The calculated digit is good. The resulting value was calculated for the value Q+1, I want to have this Q+1 value on the output.
When I call this function on Console, the function returns me correct digit value, but return me and Q value - I wish to have that Q + 1 value.

How can I achieve that?

For example:
Through the console I enter the number that 100% goes in else condition of my function. Then I want to print out that Q+1 value plus some digit...

Q = 1111; - this number goes to else condition
new Value will be Q+1 or 1112;
But when the function is completed the Q iz still 1111.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit confusing, you should use a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but assuming the function does what you want it to do, in the parameter `int Q` you are passing the value of Q not Q itselt, so the variable is unaltered, if you want to alter the value of the variable you can use `ref`, you will be passing a reference to the variable, like so:

```
public static int ControlNumber(ref int Q)
    {
        if (//some condition)
        {
          return some digit;
        }
        else
        {
            Q += 1;
            return ControlNumber(ref Q);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. In one part of the code I made a bad call to the function.
Thank you all, my answers were especially helpful anastaciu and DStanley.